# Is $\text{ker} (\delta_{\nabla^E}d_{\nabla^E})$ always non-zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, adjoint-operators

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$, equipped with a metric $\eta$ and a metric-compatible connection $\nabla$.

Denote by $\delta_{\nabla^E}:\Omega^1(M,E) \to \Omega^{0}(M,E)=\Gamma(E)$ the adjoint of the connection $${\nabla^E}: \Gamma(E)\to \Omega^1(M,E).$$

Note that $\delta_{\nabla^E}\circ{\nabla^E}: \Gamma(E) \to  \Gamma(E)$.

**Question:** Is $\text{ker} (\delta_{\nabla^E}\circ{\nabla^E})$ always non-zero?

While [it is known that $\text{ker} (\delta_{\nabla^E})$ is infinite-dimensional](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255164/is-the-kernel-of-the-coderivative-infinite-dimensional), it is not clear to me that there are non-zero elements in the $\text{ker} (\delta_{\nabla^E})$ which are in the image of $\nabla^E$.

(Note: for a generic connection $\nabla^E$, $\text{ker}(\nabla^E)=0$.

My motivation is trying to understand things about the minimizing properties of harmonic maps.

Comment: In the Riemannian case $E=TM$ this reduces to studying the Laplace-Beltrami operator on vector fields. When $M$ is compact, I think a simple Bochner-style argument shows that $X \in \ker (\Delta_g)$ implies $\nabla X=0$, so a manifold admitting no parallel vector fields should be a counterexample.

Comment: The "harmonic" implies parallel part of this works for general $(E,\nabla)$, so long as your adjoint $\delta_\nabla$ is defined using some Riemannian metric and corresponding volume form. The argument is easy: just prove the formula $\frac 12  \Delta |s|^2 = \langle \Delta s, s \rangle + |\nabla s|^2$, substitute $\Delta s = 0$ and then integrate both sides.

Comment: Is your $d_{\nabla_E}$ the same as $\nabla_E$?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes.  $d_{\nabla}:\Omega^k(M,E) \to \Omega^{k+1}(M,E)$ is the covariant exterior derivative on forms of different degrees, induced  by $\nabla$. For $k=0$, $d_{\nabla}$ coincides with $\nabla$.

Comment: I see, @AsafShachar I am just confused why you are not using the same notation.

Comment: @JohnMa Perhaps I should change it.  This was a mistake at first, but then I thought that perhaps some people will be more familiar with the notation $d_{\nabla}$ so I left it in the title. Maybe I should edit it to be consistent with the question.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks. Regarding your second comment, can you please elaborate? (What is $s$ in your example? harmonic function? harmonic vector field? gradient of a function?)

Comment: @AsafShachar: $s$ is a section in $\ker(\delta \circ \nabla).$ levap's answer is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is pretty much an expansion of Anthony Carapetis's comment together with a reference. The operator $\delta_{\nabla^E} \circ \nabla^E$ (more often denoted by $\nabla^{*} \nabla$) is called the **connection Laplacian** or the **covariant Laplacian** (see Chapter 7, Section 3.2 of Petersen). I'll assume that $(M,g)$ is compact and oriented and then by definition of the adjoint operator we have

$$ \int_{M} \left< \nabla s, \nabla s \right> \, d\operatorname{Vol}_g = \int_{M} \left< s, \nabla^{*} \nabla s \right> \, d\operatorname{Vol}_g $$

so any section in the kernel of $\nabla^{*} \nabla$ must be parallel ($\nabla s = 0$).

Since a "generic connection" admits no non-trivial parallel sections, most of the time the kernel of $\nabla^{*} \nabla$ is zero-dimensional.